# What does the p value for a covariate in a two-way ANCOVA (or factorial ANCOVA) really mean?

Tags: anova, ancova, predictor, two-way, mancova

Given that the covariate aims to reduce the variance in the error term, what does the p-value mean for a covariate in a two-way ANCOVA? I assume the "correction" is applied no matter what the p-value is. So what information does the p-value gives me about the covariate?

Let's say my covariate is "Age" and my DV is a IQ test. I have sex and education levels as IVs. If the p-value for the covariate "Age" is not significant, what can I conclude? The "age" correction was applied no matter the p-value, right?

Thank you!